# Separate folders and files with Upper case & Lower case filenames from Windows

Tags: windows-10, case-sensitive

I have folders of files with uppercase and lowercase filenames in Windows system.

For filenames starting with "a" or "A" are stored in either folder "A", or "a". All filenames starting with "b" or "B" are stored in either folder "B", or "b". etc

Currently folder names may be either uppercase "A" or lowercase "a" randomly.

Now, my task is to sort these folders and files as if they are "case-sensitive" and separate the files into different folders according to uppercase and lowercase directory names & filenames. (e.g. atF0Gxx file put under "a" folder, while A0p9xxx file put under "A" folder, and similarly for b, B, c, C, d, D... z, Z)

Can i do so in Windows 10? Can do so programmatically?

My Windows 10 file system is currently using default, so case-insensitive.
I need to sort these folders and files for import into Linux system later.

[Files with a mix of uppercase and lowercase filenames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3PaA.png)

Comment: Since Windows is case-insensitive by default, you can't have a folder named `a` and another named `A`. Windows will treat them as the same folder. (You can [opt into case-sensitivity](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/per-directory-case-sensitivity-and-wsl/).)